# Get File Value in post validator using a form in symfony 1.4

Tags: forms, validation, symfony-1.4

I have a form where you can upload a file if you select a choice, I'm trying to use a postValidator to throw an error if the user doesn't upload a file and there is not already a file uploaded

In the Form Class I have the postValidator

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkFile'))));    

public function checkFile($validator, $values){
  $file = $this->getOption('file');
  if($values['carta-compromiso'] && !$values['file'] && !$file){
    throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Debe subir el archivo de carta de compromiso.');
  }
  return $values;
}
```

And in the action I pass the value $file with

```
$this->paso1_lleno = PostulacionTable::getInstance()->findOneByUsuarioId($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId());
$this->form = new Paso1Form(array(), array('file' => $this->paso1_lleno->archivo_carta_compromiso));
```

The value I get in the post validator with $values['file'] is always null, even if I choose a file.

Comment: How are you binding the form?

Comment: with $this->form = new PostulacionPeeepForm();

Comment: No, binding is callling `$this->form->bind(...)` method, what parameters are passed in?

Comment: Sorry, I use  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('paso_1'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the files as second parameter to `bind()` method:

```
 $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('paso_1'), $request->getFiles('paso_1'));
```